# Hovering the image correctly using CSS3

Tags: css

How to make the screen image inside the phone mockup appear when I hover the phone mockup without affecting the screen image's webkit animation? There's a tutorial Im following and I followed all the things correctly but hovering the phone mockup isn't really working for the image to appear. Btw, here's the tut Im following [here](http://joelb.me/sandbox/css-crt/)

Can you please just check the javascript console to view the css file of it :-)

More details [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bretbardolees/6jP37/1/)

HTML part:

```
<body>
    <div id="nexus-mockup"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dP1JFcJ.png"></div>
    <div id="screen-image"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/F0YpTV7.gif" width="280" height="500"></div>
</body>
```

CSS part:

```
#nexus-mockup {
position: absolute;
top: 7.3%;
left: 31.6%;
}
#screen-image {
position: absolute;
top: 16.5%;
left: 35.7%;
-webkit-animation: crt-off 0.3s 0s 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation: crt-off 0.3s 0s 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;

    opacity: 0.0;
}
#nexus-mockup:hover #screen-image {
    -webkit-animation: crt-on 0.3s 0s 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation: crt-on 0.3s 0s 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes crt-on {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.005);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 9999px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 0.005);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 9999px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes crt-off {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 0.005);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 9999px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    }
    70% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.005);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 9999px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sibling Selector in CSS is `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the new CSS rules on a sibling element [you need to use `+`](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzb8n/).

```
#nexus-mockup:hover + #screen-image {
}
```

Read More : [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: WOW! this is awesome! thanks alot for the quick answer haha. Thank youu! Will pick up you after 7 mins :) THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors that prevented this from working.

1) You css rule is for one element container within the other.

```
<div id="nexus-mockup"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dP1JFcJ.png"></div>
<div id="screen-image"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/F0YpTV7.gif" width="280" height="500"></div>
```

changes to:

```
    <div id="nexus-mockup">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dP1JFcJ.png" />
        <div id="screen-image"></div>
    </div>
```

2) I'd suggest you use pixel dimensions when laying out images on top of other images.
This is because your parent container is anyhow bound by pixels of the image, so using pixels makes more sense.

Here is a working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6jP37/14/